# Jquery dropdown onchange issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dropdowns which are populating dynamically from mysql. One for banks and other one for branches. If bank dropdown change,it's banches data should be display in branch dropdown. Here I have used two separate functions to do this job and these are ok and working nicely.

This is how I defined these two functions:

```
function Banks($selecter, selected) {
 // my stuff ----
}
function Branches($selecter, bid, selected) {
 // my stuff ----
}
```

My problem is now I have set a default value for bank dropdown to display when document is ready. But its branches data is not populating. But when I changing data from bank its working.

This is how I tried it:

```
  var bankReg = $('#DropDownEdit').data('id'); 
  var branchReg = $('#branchDropDown').data('id2'); 
  Banks($('#DropDownEdit'), bankReg);
  $(document).on('change', '#DropDownEdit', function(){
    var bankID = $("#DropDownEdit").val(); 
    Branches($('#branchDropDown'), bankID, branchReg); 
  });

UPDATE:
```

my `Banks` function:

```
function Banks($selecter, selected) {  
  $selecter.empty(); 
  $selecter.append('<option>Loadding.....</option>');
  $selecter.append("<option value=''>--- Select Bank ---</option>"); 
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "includes/process_bank_dropdown_populate_ajax.php", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $selecter.empty();
      $selecter.append("<option value=''>--- Select Bank ---</option>");
      $.each(data, function(i,item){
        var selecting; 
        if (selected === data[i].bankID) {
          selecting = ' selected="selected"'; 
        } else {
          selecting = '';
        }
        $selecter.append('<option '+selecting+' value="'+data[i].bankID+'">'+data[i].bank+'</optoin>');
      });
    }, 
    complete: function() {}
  }); 
}
```

Can anybody tell me how I get this to work? 
Thank you.

Comment: Why not just populating the branches dropdown when the document is ready, maybe by checking the val of the bank dropdown?

Comment: @elio.d, I am not sure what you told, Can you kindly elaborate it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the html of the dropdown's? One other thing is why are you calling `Branches($('#branchDropDown'), bankID, branchReg);` when branchReg was not changed on change event? And by or defenition `function Branches($selecter, bid, selected)` it is the selected element.

Comment: In bank dropdown make first element value as  "Select Bank" for default choice and rest with dynamic values. So user change the bank dropdown, it automatically populate branches, because change event has triggered.

Comment: @JustinJohn, Yes I have already done it. and populating branches when bank dropdown change. But problem is I have set a default value for bank dropdown. When document is ready that default value is displaying but branches not populating.

Comment: If you can create a fiddle, would be of much help

Comment: Then call the method `Branches()` from `Banks()` method on document load, which will passed with default choice value as arguments. This is because you are not calling the branches method on page load.

Comment: @JustinJohn, Can you show me how to do it? I am trying but still I can not get it to work.

Comment: @JustinJohn, I tried with your answer. But still couldn't get it to work. Meantime I updated my question with the code of `Banks` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I can only give you a thread to solve the problem.

Call the `Branches` method inside `Banks` method.

```
function Banks($selecter, selected) {
 // my stuff ----

 // Put this inside ajax success callback as last statements
 var bankID = $("#DropDownEdit").val(); // Check this value available here or take value from success callback directly.
 var branchReg = $('#branchDropDown').data('id2'); // Check this value available here or take value from success callback directly.
 Branches($('#branchDropDown'), bankID, branchReg);

}
```

Here `bankID` and `branchReg` are default selected values. These work, if scope can accessed for above variables inside `Banks` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the bank on change to do what you want just call it after populating the default bank and it will trigger just as if you had chosen the bank by hand.

```
    $("#bankDropDownEdit").change();
```

Answer (score 0):

On document load
Hide both list initially
Get the branches for default bank and populate the list then  in callback function make both list appear

Comment: In css #dropDownEdit , #branchDropDown{display:none;}  in $.ajax() function populate lists and set the display visible

Answer (score 0):

when you assign the value to dropdown it will not call any change event, while you select from dropdown then this event will fire.

after assign value to dropdown call change event

> $("#bankDropDownEdit").change();